# Azure Firewall not Alerting on DNS test FQDN

Tags: azure

When I try to access the Azure FQDN provided for testing firewall threats I get no response, but I also do not get any alerts (Azure Portal or RESTAPI Alerts -> List) about attempting to access: `testmaliciousdomain.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com` as specified here: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/firewall/threat-intel

I have a linux VM configured to run a cronjob every minute for a simple `curl http://testmalic...` which does not get a response (expected) but it does not show any alerts in the Security Center.

I currently have configured the firewall in the proper subnet, and the vm is within that subnet and running a curl to `ipchicken` from that VM shows that my public IP is that of the public IP for the Azure Firewall.  (Additionally to access the VM [SSH] I must use the Firewall's public IP, not the VM's public IP)

Can anyone help me to get alerts reporting for the Azure Firewall whether it be this known test FQDN, or another malicious activity?

Thank you in advance, and I'm happy to elaborate on anything needed just ask!

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with a Tier 2 support specialist within Microsoft it seems that some alerts were adjusted to a Low severity (including this DNS request).  The dashboard and API are such that they only utilize alerts reported with a High severity.

For `EICAR` testing, the documentation at this URL describes both Windows and Linux VM approaches for triggering a High severity alerts for testing.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-alert-validation